# Help identifying tablet manufacturer and model to get specs

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablet

I received a 7" tablet as a "gift" when I attended a presentation recently. I'd like to find out some specs about it (processor details, who the manufacturer is in case I need support, etc.). I hope someone can help point me in the right direction...

The device came in a white and blue box that said "Android" and "Tablet PC" on it. There is no mention of any manufacturer, so my guess is I got an extremely cheap Chinese tablet. The instructions seem to indicate so...the English in it is horrible.

Based on the "About tablet" section in Settings, it seems to be running stock Android 4.0.4 and its model number is "TWD_MID". I did some searches but couldn't find any conclusive manufacturer/specs.

It has 1GB of internal storage, another "internal storage" worth 1.71GB, and it has a "TF Card" slot...which takes MicroSD cards.

Thanks in advance...

Kevin

Comment: FYI, TF stands for Transflash, which is another (maybe older) name for microSD HC.

Comment: @DanHulme to be accurate, TransFlash was the original name of microSD, SDHC came years later.

Comment: Try this. SysHard Info - show system and hardware information on Android
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kinocat.andinfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Android System Info app and it gave me a bit more hardware information (CPU speed, CPU chip, etc.) but nothing definitive about the manufacturer...I guess it will remain a mysterious an Allwinner clone...
Thanks for the help, all...

Answer (score 1):

Super easy:

1. Go to all settings
2. About Device (in my case About Phone)

Then you should see where it says `Model Number` that is your device. Mine says:

> DROID RAZR M

as the model number (not really a number but whatever).

A quick google search will give you the specs you want. Just search for your model + "specs" and you should be able to find it pretty easily.

---

Edit:

If the model number did not give you enough info, try searching the Model number along with the System Version, it might give you more information. You could also use the screen size specified in the Hardware Information to narrow your results.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "System Version" and "Hardware Information"? How do I get those 2 pieces of information?

Comment: maybe if I use the command line (terminal), there's a place to dig out the information I'm looking for?

Comment: You could get all the specs of the device from the 
Terminal, but it won't help you find out what the actual device is called.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a Google search it's either an Allwinner A13 tablet or one of it's clones, but I can't be sure, since the model number is pretty generic for cheap Chinese tablets. Some specs can be found on [Slatedroid](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/35779-allwinner-a13-tablet/).

Comment: thanks, that's about as close as I could find to specs that match up to my device...it's not perfectly accurate, but it's close.

Answer (score -1):

Download the app cpu identifier, it will tell you all thee info about your device

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail, such as a link to the app, and how exactly it will help?